# Change RelativeLayout height as user scrolls in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the height of RelativeLayout as user scrolls, so it smoothly moves up. It's kinda working but its all flickering and glitching.

I tried to use setTranslationY, but that doesn't move the scrollview with the RelativeLayout.

```
int top = mScrollView.getScrollY();
int maxRelative = formulas.dpToPx(250);
int actualRelative = (int)((1.0-((float)top)/300.0)*((float)maxRelative));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_description = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            actualRelative);
mCollapsingLayout.setLayoutParams(layout_description);
                    mCollapsingLayout.requestLayout();
```

This is how it looks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8oWB.jpg

If you have any better idea how to shrink the RelativeLayout as you scroll, its appreciated.

Edit: here's my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:id="@+id/collapsing.view">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/collapsing.view.image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/theflash"
        android:tint="#7F000000"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite.button"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/favorite_button"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="30px">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="The Flash"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/detail.scrollview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/collapsing.view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you share your layout xml file?

Comment: Yes, its in the main post now :)

Comment: Are you trying to resize whole `collapsing.view` or trying to add parallax effect to image?

Comment: Well I would like it to shrink as i scroll. So changing the whole size of the collapsing.view seemed like best idea. Idk if I should change it so the collapsing.view is inside the scrollview. Dont know if that will make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to this, including readily available classes such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/91ac8a20acfbdc410a68) which basically does what you want. You may need to remove the parts for the shrinking text and so forth, but it's right where you need it

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i need, I don't wanna use the Appcompats CollapsingToolbar because its awful when it comes to customization. I will try to dig a bit deeper into this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your `RelativeLayout` inside the `ScrollView` and try `setTranslationY` again - it should work

Comment: I tried this approach and it works, it just needs a lot of tweaking to make it look how I want :) thank you for your support